# CSS Sticky Footer - Getting content border to extend to the footer

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I know that there are tons of questions about this but I've been searching Google for 4 days now and nothing is seeming to work for me. I'm trying to implement a sticky footer - meaning that when there is not enough content to fill the screen, the footer is at the bottom of the screen and when there is enough content to fill the screen, the footer stays below that content and you scroll down.

I have tryed roughly 15 different sticky footer solutions and while most of them work in theory, my particular situation keeps messing it up  my content has borders on the left and right that should extend down to the footer. Anything involving push won't work.

Here is the most recent incarnation of what I've tried:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">

  <div id="header">
    <!--Banner goes here-->
    <div id="nav">Navigation Links</div>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <p>Content Goes Here</p>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#content {
  padding: 20px;
  border-left: solid 30px lightblue;
  border-right: solid 30px lightblue;
}


#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  border-top: solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
```

}

How do I get this sticky footer to work while also getting those blue borders to extend down to the footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses box-shadow to create the "border:" http://jsfiddle.net/FT8KR/.  The pixel values were rather arbitrary, so play with those.  Border can also be used, but it pushes the scroll bar more inwards, whereas box-shadow naturally does not.

```
#container {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -80px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    box-shadow: inset -48px 0 0 lightblue,
                inset 30px 0 0 lightblue;
}
```

Comment: This is great, but I see two problems... 1. the boxshadow intersects the header. It should not go around the header or nav links, just the content. Secondly, the footer is sticking to the bottom of the screen instead of the bottom of the content when the content is too big for the screen.

Comment: Figured it out! Not quite sure how, but I did!

Comment: Same here.  Here's the working sticking footer.  The header was adjusted using negative margins and box-shadow was replaced using just plain border.  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vhg3B/.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
  padding-bottom: 90px
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0 ;
  height: 80px;
  border-top: solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This is more or less what I implemented recently. May also require "height: 100%" on the html/body/container.

Comment: i cant understand you ! but for less file body { padding-bottom: 90px #footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0 ;
  height: 80px;
  border-top: solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
} }

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem with the borders. They're still stopping where the content does instead of extending down to the footer.

Comment: That would seem to be the intention with the footer's border-top though. You could set a "U"-shaped border on the footer (left, right, bottom), in order to have it end at the bottom of the footer's content.

Comment: Katana, I'm not sure if I'm understanding... I want the side borders to stop when the hit the footer. Currently, they're stopping way short of that (at the end of text in #content). There's a big white space between the text in #content and the footer. Not sure if that was clear...

Comment: If you can't get it to work another way, this would probably work: http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns